# Command to zip a directory using a specific directory as the root

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, command

I'm writing a PHP script that downloads a series of generated files (using `wget`) into a directory, and then zips then up, using the `zip` command.

The downloads work perfectly, and the zipping mostly works. I run the command:

```
zip -r /var/www/oraviewer/rgn_download/download/fcst_20100318_0319.zip /var/www/oraviewer/rgn_download/download/fcst_20100318_0319
```

which yields a zip file with all the downloaded files, but it contains the full `/var/www/oraviewer/rgn_download/download/` directories, before reaching the `fcst_20100318_0319/` directory.

I'm probably just missing a flag, or something small, from the zip command, but how do I get it to use `fcst_20100318_0319/` as the root directory?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I don't think zip has a flag to do that. I think the only way is something like:

```
cd /var/www/oraviewer/rgn_download/download/ && \
   zip -r fcst_20100318_0319.zip fcst_20100318_0319
```

(The backslash is just for clarity, you can remove it and put everything on one line.)

Since PHP is executing the command in a subshell, it won't change your current directory.

Answer (score 5):

I have also get it worked by using this command

exec('cd '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].' && zip -r com.zip "./"');

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Excellent, exactly looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /home/public_html/site/upload/ && zip -r sub_upload.zip sub_upload/
```

Comment: Is that exactly the same as the accepted answer ? Without explanations, it's not very useful…

Comment: This correct way 

cd /home/public_html/site/upload/sub_upload && zip -r sub_upload.zip .

Answer (score 1):

Use the -j or --junk-paths option in your zip command.

From the [zip man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip):

> -j
>
> --junk-paths
>
> Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store
> directory  names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative
> to the current  directory).