# zip files and folders which are in a particular directory

Tags: shell

How to zip files and folders which are in a particular directory using shell script?
I have `abc` directory under which there are some `.xml`, `.cfx` etc. files, and a few folder assets, res, etc. 
Now I want to zip files under `abc` folder with the name `abc.zip`

I don't want the zip to happen with the `abc` directory i.e. `abc.zip`->`abc`-> and those files;
I want `abc.zip`-> those files.

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473115/command-to-zip-a-directory-using-a-specific-directory-as-the-root

Comment: @user1201239: Be aware that what you want might not be what the person *unzipping* the archive wants. It is generally considered good behaviour to have `abc.zip` unzip to a folder `abc` with contents, instead of an archive that dumps multiple, perhaps hundreds of files into the current working directory. Ref. [tarbomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_archive#Tarbomb).