# Is threadsafe using `cd path/ && zip -r name.zip directory/`

Tags: linux, command-line, thread-safety, command, zip

I would like to zip a directory, but I need to use a full path and I need that the zip files starts in the directory, not in `/`.

That question was solved here: [Command to zip a directory using a specific directory as the root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473115/command-to-zip-a-directory-using-a-specific-directory-as-the-root)

The answer would be basically to use this: 
If I want to zip `full/path/to/directory/` in a file named myFile.zip, I would need to use the command

`cd /full/path/to/ && zip -r myFile.zip directory/`

Now, my question: is this threadsafe? without `&&` (2 commands) would be unsafe, is `&&` enough to make it threadsafe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying `command1 && command2` implies that `command2` would be executed only if `command1` exits with a return code of zero.  If `/full/path/to/` doesn't exist than the `zip` command wouldn't be executed.

Regarding the *thread safety* part, if you have multiple processes trying to create a file with the same name in a given directory, chances are that it'll lead to unexpected results.

Comment: What about having commands like `cd /full/path/to/ && zip -r myFile.zip directory/` and `cd /full2/path2/to2/ && zip -r myFile2.zip directory2/` at the same time? Could that lead to a bad execution of the commands or thread unsafety?

Comment: @DavidTorres No, that shouldn't pose any problem.